# Jet Airways connecting flight

Tags: connecting-flights

How can I manage a waiting time of 6 hours and 30 minutes at Mumbai airport, waiting for my next flight with Jet Airways?

Comment: Bring a book to read?

Answer (score 1):

You could purchase access to [a lounge in your terminal](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/bombay.htm#lounge) if you want a more comfortable place to wait with refreshments, wifi, etc...

There is also [WiFi available](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/bombay.htm#wifi) throughout the airport, though you may need to visit an information desk to get a code to activate it. I promise you that the internet has more than 6 hours and 30 minutes worth of things to see.